# Package a background service Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, service, background, installation

Is it possible to package a background service written in C# with VS 2017? From what I understand VS doesn't create an installer for services and that you need to use something like Wix Toolset. I have looked into wix toolset, but haven't found any clear documentation on how to use it. Any help would be great, as this is completely new to me.

Comment: What do you mean by package? You want to add an .exe installer...to what? Is this something that is suppose to run out of Windows services or as a desktop application?

Comment: It is strictly a background service written for a client that will monitor a folder and any new files will be uploaded to a S3 bucket. I need a way to distribute the service through an installer

Comment: Depending how you have written your project so far,  http://topshelf-project.com/ is an excellent way to turn a console app into a Windows service.

Comment: @jcc thank you, I will take a look

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [Advanced Installer extension for Visual Studio](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-ai-ext-vs.html) and see if this helps.